# How to post file with JSON content to IIS web server

Tags: json, post, python-requests

I need to post JSON file and have following code for that:

```
import requests
import sys

credential_file_name = "C:\\credentials"
with open(credential_file_name, "r") as af:
    for line in af:
        user = line.split(":")[0].strip()
        password = line.split(":")[1].strip()
        break

url_test = "http://srv190/cmdb/api2/ci"
file_json_test = open(sys.argv[1], "r", encoding="utf-8").read()
headers = {"Content-Type" : "application/json"}
ret = requests.post(url=url_test, json=file_json_test, headers=headers, auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth( user, password ), verify=False)
print(str(ret.status_code))
print(str(ret.text))
exit(0)
```

I post it to IIS web server, which accepts JSON input. The post command returns following errors:

```
400
{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"ciApi":["An error has occurred."]}}
```

and here is the content of JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "name": "test12346",
        "description": "test test",
        "summary": "Testing CI",
        "status": "Active",
        "type": "Virtual Server",
        "organisation": "IDC"
    }
]
```

I am sure the user name and password from credential file are correct.

What could be wrong in post command?

How to extend the error message for better understanding of what is going on?

What is "ModelState" - a variable, a keyword?

Where to look for better description of a problem.

Comment: You need to encode the JSON string you are posting, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp  to translate all the characters that will break the post format.

Comment: I figured it out. The JSON file should not have those outer square brackets. In the post command json= should be replaced with data=. On top of that my access to the web server was not right. Fixing all these three things helped me to make it work. In a way to solve the issue I found that using curl command can be very helpful, because the output from the web server is printed on screen and can be analysed.

Comment: The outer brackets just mean its an array consisting of 1 element.  So you have to reference with ret[0].name, also in you original code you reference ret.status_code and ret.text, but the JSON you posted doesn't have these members.

Comment: Yep, SPlatten. I'll take this into account when will update/create multiple items. It was my first attempt to make it work and some further work is expected on that code. Thank you.